# How to fetch Record row by row and save their values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

In my case, I have to fetch Questions one by one with their respective options and save the option id into answers table, I can able fetch questions one by one but not able to save option id's into answers table.

Here is my controller

```
public function getQuestion(Request $request,$qId)
{
    $questions = Question::find($qId);
    $options = Question::find($qId)->options;
    $previous = Question::where('id', '<', $questions->id)->max('id');
    $next = Question::where('id', '>', $questions->id)->min('id');
    return view('Pages/User/Questions/Question2')
                                ->with('options',$options)
                                ->with('questions',$questions)
                                ->with('previous',Question::find($previous))
                                ->with('next',Question::find($next));
}
```

My Route

```
 Route::get('/question/{qId}', [
       'uses' => 'customers\QuestionController@getQuestion',
        'as' => 'question'
 ]);
```

My view

```
@foreach      
   <h3>{{$questions->question_name}}</h3>
        @foreach($options as $option)
          <div class="checkbox">
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="option">{{$option->option}}</label>
         @endforeach
@endforeach
   @if($previous)
     <a href="{{route('question',['qId' => $previous->id])}}">Previous</a>
   @endif
   @if($next)
    <a href="{{route('question',['qId' => $next->id])}}" >Next</a>
   @endif
```

That is how code looks like I can fecth records row by row not but able to save option id in answers table because of its not there in form.

Comment: So why you dont use form?

Comment: @ Mohammad b I tried with form but could not fetch record one by one.Could you please help on this.

Comment: explain how do you want to store answers in database?

Comment: @ Mohammad b It's an online test like Questions with multiple choice, Once I fetch a question with options I just need to store the option Id which is selected by the user into answers table, I need to store question_id,option_id(selected answer),user_id.

Answer (score 0):

you should change view like this:

```
@foreach(put here main foreach loop)     
   <h3>{{$questions->question_name}}</h3>
   <form action="storeRoute">
        @foreach($options as $option)
          <div class="checkbox">
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="{{ $option->id }}">{{$option->option}}</label>
         @endforeach
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
@endforeach
   @if($previous)
     <a href="{{route('question',['qId' => $previous->id])}}">Previous</a>
   @endif
   @if($next)
    <a href="{{route('question',['qId' => $next->id])}}" >Next</a>
   @endif
```

this way selected options id send to storeRoute as an option array

and you can use foreach in controller to get selected opstions value

if you want to get all selected options one by one use this code:

```
foreach ($request->option as $opt){ 
    //code to store $opt as question answer
}
```

or if you can save all selected options `$request->option`

Comment: thanks for your answers, but I need to send option array to store route with next(hyperlink) button, Is it possible, If use submit button there will be three buttons it doesn't look good.

Comment: @ManjunathAM there are many ways to do that, for example after restore options in controller return redirect to next page url , or use jquery to submit and go next pages ,...